# Using Swift clases with overloaded methods in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, overloading

Currently, my project uses both, Swift and Objectice-C languages. To get it to work, I’ve followed the guidelines from [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/) . And now I'm able to use Swift in Objective-C, and vice versa.

But the problem arises when some of the Swift clases have overloaded methods. Swift supports method overloading but not Objective-C.

Example:

```
func random(#lower: Int , upper: Int) -> Int {
    return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
}

func random(#lower: CGFloat , upper: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random() % 1) / 0
}
```

The auto generated file “MyNameProductModule-Swift.h” can’t compile because there are methods with the “same” signature.

Questions:

a) Am I missing something important?

b) Is there any solution other than rename the methods?

c) If I will create a Framework/Library with Swift, should i take care of not writing any overloaded method if this Framework/Library is designed to use it with Objective C too?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of the conflicting methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of swift2.0 you can differentiate if you're planning on using both in Objective C:

```
@objc(randomLoInt:HiInt:)
func random(#lower: Int , upper: Int) -> Int {
    return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
}

@objc(randomLoFlt:HiFlt:)
func random(#lower: CGFloat , upper: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random() % 1) / 0
}
```

or if you're not going to use this in your ObjC side of the project at all, just use:

```
@nonobjc
func random(#lower: Int , upper: Int) -> Int {
    return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
}

@nonobjc
func random(#lower: CGFloat , upper: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random() % 1) / 0
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> a) Am I missing something important?

No you are not

> b) Is there any solution other than rename the methods?

Unfortunately not. However, you can keep the methods implemented as you have them and add two different functions that call this that are only meant for exposing to Objective-C. That way, Swift code can still use the method overloaded version.

> c) If I will create a Framework/Library with Swift, should i take care
>   of not writing any overloaded method if this Framework/Library is
>   designed to use it with Objective C too?

Yes, if you want to write a framework to be used by both Objective-C and Swift, you will need to make sure the API is fully compatible with Objective-C. There are a number of Swift features that are not compatible with Objective-C. You can still use these internally to your framework, but they cannot be made part of the API that you will expose to Objective-C.

Comment: So, these methods would compile in Objective-C if they would be marked as 'private` because they wouldn't be exposed. Is that right? Even if they are used in the same target?

Comment: @valbertos technically, they are not being compiled in Objective-C. Swift files are always compiled with the Swift compiler and Objective-C files are always compiled with the Objective-C compiler. However, the compiled Objective-C and Swift code can interact. There are some limitations in both directions (Swift doesn't allow things like associated properties, method swizzling, and other ways of modifying classes at runtime while Objective-C doesn't have Generics, Enumerations with methods, method overloading, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I encounted this same issue while i was doing Stanford University Swift course. Then i found a solution by using below link also i got the clear understanding here.

The Stanford course was made when older version of Swift and Xcode was present and Xcode didn't react on this mistake. It was a bug in XCode that it allowed to override this method. You just should write method with different name to achieve what you want.

https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/34yusl/help_with_function_overloading/